# T-SQL - How to remove text to the left of a specific character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that returns variable string lengths in the format below:

```
Example Text: More example text
```

How do I remove all the text before the colon and the colon to leave just the text to the right of the colon, so I have the result of:

```
More example text
```

The text to the right can be any length.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that "More example text" has colon?

Comment: So you want `" More example text"` with one leading space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the answer that worked for me. Script.Topic is the column name:

```
SELECT RIGHT('{Script.Topic}', len('{Script.Topic}') - charindex(':', '{Script.Topic}'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CHARINDEX to find the index of the colon, then use RIGHT to substring just the text you want:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR( MAX ) = 'Example Text: More example text'

PRINT RIGHT( @text, LEN( @text ) - CHARINDEX( ':', @text ) ) 

-- Prints " More example text"
```

To remove your leading space, you can LTRIM the output:

```
PRINT LTRIM( RIGHT( @text, LEN( @text ) - CHARINDEX( ':', @text ) ) )

-- Prints "More example text"
```

Comment: Use `LTRIM()` to remove leading space from " More example text"

Comment: From the documentation for [`Len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**." A sneaky way to hide an `RTrim()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUBSTRING` , `CHARINDEX` AND `LTRIM`:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR( MAX ) = 'Example Text: More example text'

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@Str , CHARINDEX(':',@Str)+1 , LEN(@Str)) With_Space,
LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Str , CHARINDEX(':',@Str)+1 , LEN(@Str))) Without_Space
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/QMZ99542).